# Kivy text input and output

Tags: python, input, kivy

I am new to `Python` (version `3.6.1`) and have just started using `Kivy` as my `GUI`.

What I want to do is to create a command line in `Kivy` which lets the user type in a command, processes the command and then outputs what needs to be output in the same text "box". It should work exactly like a `Windows` commmand line, but it has to be a part of the `Kivy` interface.

The closest I ever got to that was using the `kivy.uixTextInput`, however, I have no idea how to fetch the user input and then how to print to that text box the output. Please help, I am struggling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `py` file:

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class MainWindow(BoxLayout):

    # We create a dictionary of all our possible methods to call, along with keys
    def command_dict(self):
        return {
            'one': self.command_one,
            'two': self.command_two,
            'three': self.command_three
        }

    def process_command(self):
        # We grab the text from the user text input as a key
        command_key = self.ids.fetch_key_and_process_command.text

        # We then use that key in the command's built in 'get_method' because it is a dict
        # then we store it into a variable for later use
        called_command = self.command_dict().get(command_key, 'default')

        try:
            # The variable is a method, so by adding we can call it by simple adding your typical () to the end of it.
            called_command()

        except TypeError:
            # However we use an exception clause to catch in case people enter a key that doesn't exist
            self.ids.fetch_key_and_process_command.text = 'Sorry, there is no command key: ' + command_key

    # These are the three commands we call from our command dict.
    def command_one(self):
        self.ids.fetch_key_and_process_command.text = 'Command One has Been Processed'

    def command_two(self):
        self.ids.fetch_key_and_process_command.text = 'Command Two has Been Processed'

    def command_three(self):
        self.ids.fetch_key_and_process_command.text = 'Command Three has been Processed'

class MainApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return MainWindow()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

In your `kv` file, (mine is called `mainapp.kv`):

```
<MainWindow>:
    Label:
        text: 'This is a label'
    TextInput:
        # We give TextInput an id to reference it in the actual code
        id: fetch_key_and_process_command

        # We set multiline to False, so we can use the next property (on_text_validate)
        multiline: False

        # on_text_validate will called MainWindow's process_command() when a user presses enter
        on_text_validate: root.process_command()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked absolutely brilliant. However, there are two technical issues that I cannot get over:
1. How can I print the message below the code without substituting it?
I want it to be printed like this:
one
Command One Has Been Processed
two
Command Two Has Been Processed

2. I have to click on the command line to enter the next command, is the any workaround which allows me to keep typing commands without using my mouse at all? 
Thank you for your effort

Comment: self.ids.fetch_key_and_process_command.text = '' <- Put this whenever you need to clear the text box, then you should be able to do it.